# how to make image in texturepacker to use in corona for sprites

Tags: coronasdk

hey m beginner to corona...how to make image in texturepacker to use in corona for sprites...
i have tried but it plays the all the  images at once ...

Comment: Please explain your problem in more detail. I don't know what you mean by "plays all at once."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should explain your problem better because just saying "plays all at once" is vague, but in the meantime here's the documentation about spritesheets in case you haven't seen this: http://developer.anscamobile.com/reference/sprite-sheets

It sounds like you may not have made separate animation sequences and so all the frames are being played as one continuous sequence. Look for the commands sprite.newSpriteSet() and sprite.add() to handle the sequencing.

Comment: sir i didnt aad the test.lua file to arrange data...every thing else i hv done about that...